# Is selling future receivables on discount haram?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I work as a freelancer, and have been selected as a candidate for the Advance Cash Program by the freelancing site due to my exceptional track record. Here is there terms:

`[Company name] Cash Advance Program lets freelancers sell a portion of their future revenue in exchange for a one-time payment. [Company name] takes 40% of the revenue until they receive the total future revenue amount. The funding amount paid to the freelancer is considered a purchase and sale of future revenue, not a loan. The freelancer represents that they have the authority to enter into the agreement and that the information provided is true and accurate. The freelancer agrees to comply with all applicable laws and regulations.`

For example, if they pay me $1.5K now, they'll be deducting $1.76K from my earnings, on a rate of 40% on every client.

I was only able to find one answer on a fatwa website: https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/102637/business-merchant-cash-advances-for-future-receivables-are-not-permissible/

Their the Mufti likened it to a Bai Al-Dayn transaction, and deemed it haram. But I wasn't able to find it on any other fatwa site. I just want to double check this before I decide not to take this "loan".

Answer (score -2):

**Similar to other *employment*** Marketplace merchant processor facilitator platform fees can steward income to partners, and this person can invest on your sales in the platform, or some proprietor contract within a certain industry.

> He sets forth for you an example ˹drawn˺ from your own lives: would you allow some of those ˹bondspeople˺ in your possession to be your equal partners in whatever ˹wealth˺ We have provided you, keeping them in mind as you are mindful of your peers? This is how We make the signs clear for people who understand. (30:28)

***Expiring schedules and scalping commodities carrying storage and transport viability*** Just make sure you do not conceal documentation, as the independent contractor either individual or sole proprietor (*otherwise subject to consumer fraud litigation*).

> Moses assured ˹him˺, “You will find me patient, Allah willing, and I will not disobey any of your orders.” He responded, “Then if you follow me, do not question me about anything until I ˹myself˺ clarify it for you.” So they set out, but after they had boarded a ship, the man made a hole in it. Moses protested, “Have you done this to drown its people? You have certainly done a terrible thing!” He replied, “Did I not say that you cannot have patience with me?” Moses pleaded, “Excuse me for forgetting, and do not be hard on me.” (18:69-73)